# Ubuntu 17.04 - JDK 9 with IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.3 issue

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk, intellij

To make it simple,
When I tried OpenJDK 9, IntelliJ IDEA won't startup, just showing an error dialog saying something like

> com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   (And alot of things after this)

When I tried Oracle Java JDK 9, IntelliJ IDEA did startup, but with Android Support plugin enabled, whenver I tried to open or create a project, this dialog shows up saying it failed to initialize plugin org.jetbrains.android then shutdown IntelliJ itself. If I disable Android Support plugin,it works just fine!
Everything is fine with JDK 8(Both Oracle and OpenJDK).

Comment: Use Java 8. Java 9 is not officially released as stable yet. You might be experiencing a bug in that one. Better report it.